# Will Mysql create new session for each event execution?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

Not sure what session will be use for event execution. Will mysql always create new session or just reuse old while executing event ?  what happens to user-defined variable ? what happen if different events use same user-defined variable( I know it is not good to use user-defined var here, but need to know what's the result).

some example code to explain a little bit:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent_a
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute
DO
  Set @a = ...
  UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = @a;

CREATE EVENT myevent_b
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute
DO
  Set @a = ...
  UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = @a;
```

will @a be read/write concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with MySql 7.7.31.

It seem that MySql will use a new session each time the event is run.

Test for yourself by saveing the session id in a table:

```
INSERT INTO my_log_table (RunTime, ID)
  VALUES (NOW(), CONNECTION_ID());
```

So each time the event runs, it will have its own set of user-defined variables.